# Find combinations of number that add up to a specified sum in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column in which numbers are written. I need from these numbers to find all combinations of 2,3,4,5 numbers that will give a certain sum with max. deviation -1%

[image: here is the expected output]

Is it even possible to do this?

Comment: I guess your best bet would be to look for an add-on that could do this...

Answer (score 0):

Given your example sheet shown in the question, you can try the following in E3 to show all the combinations of two numbers from the list whose sum is within 1% of the target sum in C2.

```
=arrayformula(let(
numbers,$A$2:$A$10,
target,$C$2,
choose,2,
splitdigits,lambda(array,map(array,lambda(each,mid(each,sequence(1,len(each)),1)))),
permuts,base(sequence(counta(numbers)^choose,1,0),counta(numbers),choose),
splitpermuts,1*splitdigits(permuts),
combos,unique(byrow(splitpermuts,lambda(row,join(,large(row,sequence(1,choose)))))),
splitcombos,1*splitdigits(combos),
combolookup,xlookup(splitcombos,sequence(count(numbers),1,0),numbers),
filtercombosbytarget,filter(combolookup,isbetween(byrow(combolookup,lambda(row,sum(row))),0.99*target,1.01*target)),
ifna(byrow(filtercombosbytarget,lambda(row,join(", ",row))),"No combos")))
```

I am assuming repeating combinations are allowed - the logic would need to be changed slightly if this is not the case. To modify the formula for 3/4/5 combinations, copy the above formula into F3:H3 and modify the choose parameter accordingly.